# Añadir parámetro de POST al hacer Web Scraping

Tags: php

Necesito hacer web scraping con PHP a esta página: 
https://es.trueketeke.com/anuncios-segunda-mano/provincia/madrid/madrid

El problema es que necesito enviar un parámetro que sería el string de la búsqueda, digamos que quiero buscar un iPhone 6, ¿Cómo puedo añadir ese parámetro si los de la página trabajan con POST?

PS: El web scraping lo hago con: file_get_content o con curl.

Muchas gracias

Comment: Utilizan GET para realizar búsquedas, la url es: https://es.trueketeke.com/api/truekes?filter= + tus query params encodeados.

Comment: Si necesitas enviar post debes usar curl, ¿qué llevas hecho hasta el momento?

Comment: Vale, pero como añado el parametro de iPhone 6 por curl?

Answer (score 0):

Podés enviar peticiones POST con CURL:

```
// Creamos un canal CURL
$canal = curl_init();

// Configuramos el canal
curl_setopt($canal, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://es.trueketeke.com/anuncios-segunda-mano/provincia/madrid/madrid');
curl_setopt($canal, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($canal, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

// Configuramos los parámetros, igual que si fuera una petición GET
curl_setopt($canal, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'parametro1=valor&parametro2=valor2');

// Deshabilitamos la verificación SSL para dominios HTTPS
curl_setopt($canal, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($canal, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);

// Ejecutamos el CURL
$respuesta = curl_exec($canal);

// Mostramos la respuesta
var_dump($respuesta);

// Debug: por si algo anda mal, revisamos el mensaje de error
var_dump('Error #' . curl_errno($canal) . ': ' . curl_error($canal));
```